# Don't want icons on my TabWidget

Tags: android

I'm still learning about Android, and while playing around with `TabHost` and `TabWidget`, I can't help but notice that there's no option to turn off the icons.

It's eating up valuable space even when I don't actually set an icon into the `TabSpec`. Is there any way to reduce the height of the tab bar? It's really hard to find small icons (at 3 different sizes) that perfectly fits what I intended those tabs to contain. I have zero skills with graphics.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have this:

```
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
```

Add code to add tabs into tab host... and then finally

```
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 25;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 30;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 35;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 50;
```

Which (if you do not have pics) results in this:[image]

It looks like 35 is a good number.. Perhaps it needs to be changed for different dpi.

Comment: Absolute height is bad I think. Is there any relative height, so that it's still good when the users use different font size?

Answer (score 1):

`getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setHeight(10)` method we can set the height for the tabs

Comment: Maybe that's for an older android version? There's no setHeight() in View.